# Getting notepad++ to associate "wscript" with Python files

Tags: notepad++

(related to [How can I tell Notepad++ to always use a particular language with a particular file extension](https://superuser.com/questions/151597/how-can-i-tell-notepad-to-always-use-a-particular-language-with-a-particular-f) )

I want to have Notepad++ to associate `wscript` files with the Python language. Is there a way to do this? It has no extension.

Comment: There is nothing stopping you giving them an extension. `vbs` for example. `vba` and `js` would also be appropriate.

Comment: No, that is not appropriate. I am using a tool called `waf` which mandates using a file named `wscript` with no extension. Please don't assume this is an xy-problem.

Comment: I didn't suggest it was. Clearly you have missed important information from the question.

Comment: "..." ok... I stated the question exactly as I wanted to.

Comment: I don't know of any way to do this automatically, but menu > language > python will do want when the `wscript` file has been opened ...

Comment: yeah, I do that now, except then I forget when I reopen `wscript`, then it fails when I start putting tabs my mistake, then I choose Python as the language and replace tabs with spaces to get it working again. (lather rinse repeat)

Comment: Why don't you configure Notepad++  to always replace tabs with spaces?

Comment: because I want to be able to use tabs in other files.

Answer (score 1):

Create a [symlink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_symbolic_link) to the wscript file but give the link the correct extension, e.g.

```
mklink /H wscript.py wscript
```

When you edit the wscript.py file you should find that notepad correctly treats it as a Python file.

Comment: +1 for creativity, but I have a bunch of these directories and I don't want to have to do that in each case.