# Change style for extensions that already have a style in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, syntax-highlighting, styles

I've already tried the answers from [here](https://superuser.com/questions/40876) and [here](https://superuser.com/questions/151597) and neither fixed my problem.

In Notepad++ using the Obsidian theme, the syntax highlighting for JSON files disappears; everything is white on black. I could go through and change them manually, but instead I would rather just use the JavaScript style instead (which does work).

I can do this with Language --> JavaScript, but if I close the file and reopen it doesn't stick.

When I try the solutions tagged above it does not work for me because JSON already has an entry and it is using the default JSON style instead of the JavaScript style. I want to override the existing style and use the JavaScript style instead.

Comment: This answer [Assigning custom extensions to a language's syntax highlighting in Notepad++](//superuser.com/a/40877) should solve your issue

Comment: See also [How can I override a default file extension for Notepad++?](//stackoverflow.com/q/7043544)

Comment: @DavidPostill thanks, the second answer worked, but I did have to make a small adjustment; I had to remove the ext="json" entry from the JSON language section as well.