# How do I get Notepad++ to associate a file type with a language?

Tags: notepad++, file-association, syntax-highlighting

I have associated `.wxs` files with Notepad++. So far so good. However, it doesn't remember that it should use XML syntax highlighting. How do I associate a file-type with a Language?

Comment: similar question: http://superuser.com/questions/40876/assigning-custom-extensions-to-a-languages-syntax-highlighting-in-notepad

Answer (score 279, accepted):

As here is mentioned : [ASSOCIATE FILE EXTENSIONS WITH SPECIFIC LANGUAGES IN NOTEPAD++](http://allthingsmarked.com/2009/07/29/associate-file-extensions-with-specific-languages-in-notepad-plus-plus/) you should do :

> In Notepad++ navigate to Settings > Style Configurator…
>
> Choose a language on the left side that you want your own extension to match (i.e. if I want .config files to style like XML then I’d choose XML). In the User ext. field near the bottom, enter in your custom user extension without the dot in front of it (e.g. config for *.config files). Now restart Notepad++ and it will map that new extension to the style you’ve chosen.
>
> NOTE: Make sure you are running Notepad++ using Administrator privileges, otherwise the settings won't be saved when you click "Save and Close".
> [image]

Comment: Could you summarise the contents of the link in your answer, so that we don't lose it if that link goes dead for some reason?

Comment: @fredley ok, The answer has updated !

Comment: Hear, hear!!!!!

Comment: Also, it’s worth noting that if you make this change and have a file open already, Notepad++ will cache the file’s current no-language selection. This means that you will need to specifically close the file in Notepad++ before it will recognize the extension.

http://todd.ropog.com/2012/get-notepad-to-recognize-any-file-extension/

Comment: "Restarting" Notepad++ doesn't work.  You need to close and reopen the file, actually.

Comment: does not work if the extension has a dot (`.`) in it.

Comment: As of v7.4.2 (Jun 18, 2017) I can confirm just restarting worked for me.

Comment: This seems to not work if there are conflicts....for example, I want xml files to open as java, doing the above does not work.

Comment: On `XML` I add `csproj` so Visual Studio solutions get highlighting