# Adding a file type association to Notepad++ not working (Yes I checked the other answers)

Tags: notepad++, language, css

How my situation is different from the solutions presented in this thread ([Assigning custom extensions to a language's syntax highlighting in Notepad++](https://superuser.com/questions/40876/assigning-custom-extensions-to-a-languages-syntax-highlighting-in-notepad)) is that I would like to add .css.liquid and associate it to display using the CSS language settings. Now, I understand that this naming scheme says that .liquid is the file type. However, .liquid is being associated (successfully thanks to the above mentioned link) to display using the HTML language settings. I tried editing the langs.model.xml directly by adding css.liquid to it without success as seen below.

< Language name="css" ext="css css.liquid" commentStart="/*" commentEnd="*/" >

So is this idea possible or just a | dream?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20019323/is-it-possible-in-notepad-to-associate-a-file-extension-with-a-dot-in-it) - it makes clear that notepad++ cannot accept dot in file extension - it always matches only part after last dot. So **css.liquid** will NOT match your file in current version of Notepad++.

---

2018 EDIT: now the linked Q/A shows this should be possible with some hacking. See more details there.