# Notepad++ ÙDL for .log.* extensions?

Tags: notepad++

I downloaded the style from https://gist.github.com/mmdemirbas/3713724

This works only for extension *.log.

my log files are with following extensions: log, log.1,log.2, log.xx after log rotation.

How/where I can set this UDL for all extensions with .log.* file types?

Comment: You can just edit the .UDL file, or copy it and edit the copy changing the `ext="log"` to something more appropriate.

Comment: can I add more than ? like `ext="log , log.*"`?

Comment: I don't know about that, but you could try it... or look at the UDL documentation.

Comment: Answers to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/40876/assigning-custom-extensions-to-a-languages-syntax-highlighting-in-notepad) indicate you can list multiple extensions, separated by a space. You can use the GUI, or edit the userDefineLang.xml file directly. The wildcard might not work, but "log.1 log.2 log.3 log.4 log.5" should.